# JQuery Data Tables isn't working after few minutes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, cdn

I have used JQuery Data Tables for one of my website. It worked well until to a certain time and now that page only show the normal table without modifying it by datatables. Is there any reason for such a thing ? Is there any fixes for that ?

First I used CDN files, but when it stopped working I put the files with the website locally without using cdn. But the problem didn't went off.

And also I tried with clearing cached content of the browser. But the problem didn't over. In some times something like randomly tables comes to working states and again it won't work without any modification by me.

Is there any reason for this ? Any fix for this ?

**Update:**

I figured out the issue.
It's because I have tried to stop auto sorting by this

"aaSorting": [],

or by this

"bSort": false,

But when I remove them, data tables looks like again as it should looks like.
But the date column is automatically sorted with asc order. But I'm trying to stop that. Because the data I already sorted with date on desc order.

Comment: What browsers have you tested it in? How are scripts built in your application? i.e. do you add the tags manually to the HTML script or are they compressed and generated using MVC bundle?

Comment: Chome, Firefox, Torch I tested with them.

yes I add them manually. using script tags.

Comment: Has to be one or more of three things (i) HTML, (ii) javascript, (iii) Doctype. Check what's actually served, not just the source.

Comment: Sorry I din't got the point. What you mean by html ? javascript ? doctype ?

Is there specific doctype for fix that ?

Comment: doctype is html 5 version.which is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed the code you are using. It is impossible to guess - there could be 100 answers.

Comment: I have updated the details. I figured out when this happens. But I have no fix for that.